# SignalR custom method to redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I have made SignalR custom methods to redirect users if they want to join group that already has 2 members. Everything seems to be working fine except the redirect method.

ChatHub.cs:

```
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        static string test2 = "";
        public static Dictionary<string, int> rooms = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        public void Test(string groupName)
        {
            if (!rooms.ContainsKey(groupName))
            {
                rooms.Add(groupName, 1);

            }
            else if(rooms[groupName] != 2)
            {
                rooms[groupName] = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                test2 = "testing";
                Redirect();
            }

        }

        public Task Redirect()
        {
            return Clients.Caller.redirectTo();
        }

        public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
        { 
            return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName); 

        }
    }
}
```

Scripts:

```
var chat2 = $.connection.chatHub;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    chat2.server.test(roomId);

    chat2.client.redirectTo = function () {
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }

    chat2.server.joinGroup(roomId);
});
```

When there are already 2 clients in a group, test2 is set to "testing" but client does not get redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your scripts to:

```
var chat2 = $.connection.chatHub;
// var roomId = "R1" <-- I added this for testing

chat2.client.redirectTo = function () {
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848709/signalr-custom-method-to-redirect#35857376");
}

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    chat2.server.joinGroup(roomId);
    chat2.server.test(roomId);
});
```

**Note**: in your `Test` method the logic says that the redirect will only run if `rooms` dictionary contains the given *roomname* and the int value corresponding to that *roomname* is '2'. Probably not your real planned logic.

For testing I added to the backed code:

```
  public static Dictionary<string, int> rooms = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  public void Test(string groupName) // <-- I sent "groupName: R1" from js 
     {
        rooms["R1"] = 2;
        if ...
     }
```